# Positional Audio In Three JS - HRTF's

Tags: three.js, web-audio-api

I just wanted to check - can three.js use HRTF's in creating positional audio. The documentation (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/audio/PositionalAudio) says it uses web Audio API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Web_audio_spatialization_basics) - in which you can use HRTFs as your panner model (const pannerModel = 'HRTF';), but three.js doesn't say anywhere that you can use an HRTF within it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.PositionalAudio` uses `HRTF` by default. If you want to change it, you can always do this:

```js
positionalAudio.panner.panningModel = 'equalpower';
```

`three.js R110`